# i can't get e.values (for sheets) or e.responses (for Forms) to work

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to fill out a google form on a jobsite and when I submit, I need a pdf containing the submitted info to be emailed to my office.

Here's where I'm at so far:

```
 // Get template from Google Docs and name it
var docTemplate = "12vZhIPt1CkWPCCN3jRE1Kpbp0dBW3key-4I_Stz0vNc"; 
var docName = "JobsiteInspectionReport";  

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
//Get information from form and set as variables

var variablename = "static entry or form value"
var email_address = "mike.onlineconstruction@gmail.com, mwfoshee@gmail.com";


//  Use this section to assign static values  

  var jobsite = "test data";
  var date_time = "test data2";
  var submit_name = "test data3";
  var weather = "test data4";
  var temp = "test data5";
  var super_name = "test data6";
  var job_num = "test data7";

// Use this section when attached to form 

  var jobsite = e.responses[2];
  var date_time = e.responses[3];
  var submit_name = e.responses[4];
  var weather = e.responses[5];
  var temp = e.responses[6];
  var super_name = e.responses[7];
  var job_num = e.responses[8]; 

// Use this section when attached to a sheet

  var jobsite = e.values[2];
  var date_time = e.values[3];
  var submit_name = e.values[4];
  var weather = e.values[5];
  var temp = e.values[6];
  var super_name = e.values[7];
  var job_num = e.values[8]; 


  //General Items 

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)

.makeCopy(docName+' for '+jobsite)
.getId();
// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document’s body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('keySiteName', jobsite);
copyBody.replaceText('keyDateTime', date_time);
copyBody.replaceText('keySubmitName', submit_name);
copyBody.replaceText('keyWeather', weather);
copyBody.replaceText('keyTemp', temp);
copyBody.replaceText('keySuperName',super_name);
copyBody.replaceText('keyJobNum', job_num);

// Save and close the temporary document
copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Convert temporary document to PDF
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

// Attach PDF and send the email
var subject = "Jobsite Inspection Report";
var body = "Here is the Jobsite Inspection Report for " + jobsite + "";
MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

// Delete temp file
DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

I have installed the onFormSubmit trigger for both sheets and forms and have successfully sent emails with attachments from scripts in both forms and sheets by deleting the e.values (in the sheets script I use e.response when the script is installed on a form) and assigning static values to the variables (see the section of code marked "Use this section when attached to form"). I receive an email, on the correct template with the correct static data.

When I try to use the e.values or e.responses section, nothing. I don't even get an email or error.

I did get an email (several in fact) a few hours later stating "TypeError: Cannot read property "2" from undefined. (line 25, file "Code")" I'm thinking the e.values[2] is my problem (or the way it's formatted, or more specifically defined). The script appears to be looking for the form?

Comment: Do you view the Execution Transcript to see if the entire script completed?  Whenever you get unexpected results, under the VIEW menu, choose Execution Transcript.  If there was an error, it will tell you what line the error occurred on.  Read the [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting) page.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the transcript, When I try to run the script by submitting the form (onFormSubmit trigger attached to the response spreadsheet) The transcript is empty and prompts me to "run some scripts". When I run the script in the editor page I get the undefined error as the form values (e.values) has not been created. (the way I understand it)

Comment: I did get an email (several in fact) a few hours later stating "TypeError: Cannot read property "2" from undefined. (line 25, file "Code")"  I'm thinking the e.values[2] is my problem (or the way it's formatted, or more specifically defined). The script appears to be looking for the form?

Comment: Running the script from the script editor will result in `e` having nothing in it, since `e` gets it's information from the form being submitted.  You can get around that problem by "hard coding" some values.  For example:  `var jobsite = "Test Jobsite";`.  I'm wondering if the script is not even being triggered to run?  You can put in a `Logger.log("onFormSubmit ran!");` statement right at the top of your code, just to check if the function is actually getting triggered.  Then VIEW, the LOGS, after submitting the form.

Comment: Get rid of the letter "s" on `e.responses`.  should be:  `e.response`.  No "s" on the end.

Comment: Thanks Sandy, I actually caught the response vs responses error last night. as far as hard coding the data, I think I tried that. look at my code under the comment "use this section to assign static values" when I use that section, I "comment out" the other two and run the script in the form and in the editor window and it runs flawlessly. Is that what you meant by "hard coding"? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  If the code runs flawlessly with the hard coded data, then there's nothing wrong with the code.  And you fixed the typo error.  So, what's left?  Somethings wrong with the trigger I think.

Comment: Like I said, When the data is "hard coded" I have successfully run the script by going to the form and actually submitting it. the script then runs and fills in the response spreadsheet opens the template fills in the blanks with the "hard coded" values then generates two emails with the template attached. I'm wondering about a setting on the form or spreadsheet that is not allowing the e.values or e.response to function. or possibly permission?

Comment: It's got to be something like that, yes.  Unfortunately, I don't have any specific ideas about what the problem might be.  Maybe try to run either the spreadsheet trigger, or the form trigger, but not both?  I'm just making wild guesses at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I now know how to use the event and log tabs in the view menu :-) Sadly, I have tried using the triggers one at a time, still no luck!

Comment: When I get to this point, I usually start from the beginning:  Create a new function.  Add a new trigger for that function.  Put in a `Logger.log('it ran')` statement, and nothing else.  See if it runs.  If even that doesn't work, then I'd start thinking that it's a bug.  But, then you'd want to create a new form with, like, just one item, and test that.  Most programming is tedium, not brilliance.

Comment: This next code worked for me, try and let me know if it works for you:   var jobsite = e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  var date_time = e.response.getItemResponses()[1].getResponse(); ...and so on..

Answer (score 1):

The submit event object needs further work before you can access it the way you are indicating. If you want to access the responses as a simple array you'll need to transform from a FormResponse object and the indiidual ItemResponse values

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  // you need to add this line to add offline event object access auth
  // run once in script editor - you could delete it after if you want
  var f = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  // test for response and use static if none exists
  var responses = [
    "test data",
    "test data2",
    "test data3",
    "test data4",
    "test data5",
    "test data6",
    "test data7"
  ];

  responses = (e && e.response) ? 
    e.response.getItemResponses()
              .map(function (r) {
                return r.getResponse();
              }) : (e && e.values) ? e.values : responses;

  // snip //

  var jobsite = responses[2];
  var date_time = responses[3];
  var submit_name = responses[4];
  var weather = responses[5];
  var temp = responses[6];
  var super_name = responses[7];
  var job_num = responses[8]; 

  // snip //

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up and started over and and it works! the script is the same as the one listed above (without all the commented sections I used while troubleshooting). the only thing I can say might be different are the setting on the form itself. For anyone having this same issue, I would check the settings on the form. On the form that works, the setting "Allow responders to edit responses after submitting" is un checked where as I think this was checked on the first form I used. If that's not it, I'm still at a loss.